# 500 Internet Server Error after Form submitting

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5

i started the laracast tutorial laravel 5.4 from scratch. Now i'm in session 12 and have my first bug. i GET A 500 Internet Server Error after submitting a empty form. I try a lot, but i can't fix it.

Here are the relevant code:

web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'PostsController@index');
Route::get('/posts/create', 'PostsController@create');
Route::post('/posts', 'PostsController@store');
```

PostController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()      
    {
      return view('posts.index');
    }

     public function show()
    {
        return view('posts.show');
    }
    public function create()
    {
        return view('posts.create');
    }
        public function store()
    {
            $this->validate(request, [
                'title' => 'required',
                'body'=> 'required'
            ]);
            Post::create(request(['title', 'body']));
            return redirect('/');          

    }

}
```

create.blate.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')


@section ('content')

<h1>Publish a Post</h1>
<hr>
<form method="POST" action="/posts">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="body">Body</label>
    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="body" name="body" ></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Publish</button>
</form>

@endsection
```

Post.php

```
<?php

namespace App;


class Post extends Model
{

}
```

Model.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Model extends Eloquent
{
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

hope someone can help me, laravel don't give me an error.

Best regards

Comment: Your main problem is that laravel doesn't give you an error. You should first amend that.

Comment: I know nothing about larvel but assume it is web based. Therefore, you need to look in your web server error log file for the issue.

Comment: check you log, show it.

Comment: Your http server writes an error log file. Locate it and look inside. That always is the _first_ step to do if you run into issues when working on web stuff.

Comment: Laravel does give you the full error stack-trace if you have Debug=true in your .env file. can . you post the error ?

Comment: debug is allready true: APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug

Comment: i dont get any error just a 500 browser error page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the bug and fix it...

PostController.php

replace:

```
$this->validate(request, [ 'title' => 'required', 'body'=> 'required' ]);
```

with:

```
$this->validate(request(), [ 'title' => 'required', 'body'=> 'required' ]);
```

Comment: try creating a validation file. Makes the code cleaner and easier to change validations. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation Also $this->validate(request, [ 'title' => 'required', 'body'=> 'required' ]); should work just do:  public function store(Request $request)

Answer (score 0):

If laravel didn't give you a error.You could set php internal error hints in you code and see what happened.

```
error_reporting (E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: this is not necessary in laravel. you set error reporting in your .env file

Comment: Ok, it is the same principle.